# llvm-prof is removed in LLVM 4.0.

Tags: llvm, instrumentation

I wish to do path profiling. I am using LLVM 4.0. After building and llvm I don't find llvm-prof tool. Is it removed? What are the options available for profiling now? Should I use older versions of LLVM?.

I also don't find profiling passes in /lib/Transformation!
Is there a repository of passes which I can use?

Comment: llvm-prof has been removed quite a long time ago AFAIK. You should start by reading http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profile-guided-optimization

Comment: http://www.llvm.org/pre-releases/4.0.0/rc2/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-profdata.html

Seems it's there..